# custom listview imageview error

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi i am creating a custom listview with texview ,imageview and i am accessing the data from sqlite database where i am storing name of each image and placing the images in assests folder when  i try access it using the holder.mimage.setImageResource(list.get(position).getImage());
it is giving the error how can i access it any suggestion will be very helpfull

```
public class InteractiveArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PosHolder> {
String tag = "Events";
private final List<PosHolder> list;
private final Activity context;
int li,jh;



public InteractiveArrayAdapter(Activity context, List<PosHolder> list) {
    super(context, R.layout.row, list);
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}

 static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView text;
    protected CheckBox checkbox,checkbox1;
    protected RadioGroup mgroup;
    protected RadioButton mbutton;
    protected ImageView mimage;
}




public View getView( final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //Log.d(tag," 3");

     View view =null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        //System.out.println("ok");
        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        viewHolder.mimage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);




           view.setTag(viewHolder);
           viewHolder.mimage.setTag(list.get(position));


    } else {
        view = convertView;
        ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).mimage.setTag(list.get(position));


    }
     ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    view.getTag()).mgroup.getTag();
     holder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
     holder.mimage.setImageResource(list.get(position).getImage());//This line is showing the error

    return view;

}
public class PosHolder {
private String name;
private String smallimage;


public PosHolder(String name, String smallimage) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    this.name=name;
    this.smallimage=smallimage;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getImage() {
    return smallimage;
}
public void setImage(String phone) {
    this.smallimage = phone;
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's becoz you are passing name of image to the imageView not the IMAGE. you are retrving imageName instand of image from the list of PosHolder object. Your PosHolder object giving you string not the image

```
public String getImage() 
{     
    return smallimage; 
}
```

this is causing exception.

Comment: thanks for replay is there any way to set the image by using its name any function because i dont know about bitmap

Comment: yep you can do it by giving it's drwable name. <code> public int getImage()  {          return R.drawable.myImage;  } </code> where myImage is name of my image.

Answer (score 0):

error is because you are not instanciating the fields of the "ViewHolder" class.
they are still null at the time you are setting the imageResource to it.